# action on jbutton press

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I can't figure out how to make the following code work.  When you press a jbutton I want it to run the following code.  My problem is that the ArrayList list is located in the main and I don't know how to pass it into this method provided to me by the GUI builder so that, that actionperformed method will know what list is and return an ArrayList back to the main to replace it with the new changes.

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Student temp;

            Picker pick = new Picker(list);
            temp = pick.randomNoReplace();  //replace randomNoReplace() with radio button choice
            list.remove(temp);              //the next line must be temp.increaseScore() or temp.decreaseScore() or neither

            list.add(temp);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `ArrayList` should be an instance variable

Comment: so I should be passing the ArrayList in like this               JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Random Names",ArrayList list);                   If so then that means I need to modify the JButton Class and I don't see how to do that.

Comment: You can make `list` as `static` member of the class containing `main()` and then call it in your action listener statically like `<your-class-name>.list`.

Comment: No, you should declare the ArrayList as an instance level variable, so it can be accessed from anywhere within an instance of your current class

Comment: I like the idea of making it an instance variable but I don't know how.  Could you please elaborate.  Do you need to see more of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
class Foo {
    private ArrayList<Student> list;
    ...
```

This will declare list as an `ArrayList` of Students as an instance variable so that each object of this class can access `list` from any instance method.  Just be sure to instantiate list before using it, preferably inside your constructor doing something like this:

```
list = new ArrayList<Student>();
```